# RESTLet 2.0.9 - query regarding multiple @Get and @Post annotations?

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

I am new to RESTLet and using 2.0.9. What I want to do is have multiple methods with @Get & @POST annotation. I have access to the VO classes  (value objects) and so I don't need to use JSON or XML representation. I have used the excellent tutorial available at http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html#dsy303-restlet_jse. I have designed the following classes:

User - VO POJO with attributes for an User. 
UserResource inteface:

```
public interface UserResource 
{ 
    @Get 
    public User userLogin();    
 }
```

For single @Get annotation, the client code works fine.

```
     ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(url); 
     // Get the Contact object 
     UserResource resource = cr.wrap(UserResource.class); 
     User user = resource.userLogin();*
```

Now, I want to use multiple methods with @Get annotation. For e.g., have two/three flavors of getUser objects similar to what we have in normal DAO layer in single JVM.

```
User getUser(int userId) 
User getUser(String domain, String username) 
boolean isUserNew(int userid)*
```

and similar multiple methods to update and add users [@POST annotation]:

```
int addUser(User user) 
int updateUser(int userId, User user)
```

Is it possible to achieve some thing like this ? If not what are the alternative ? Where can I get documentation for Annotations @Get, @Post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way this is meant to be done is having:

- `UsersResource` with a `@Get` annotated method that fecthes a user by it's unique id;
- `UsersDomainUsernameResource` (similar fetch logic...)

`@Get` methods will then handle various cases:

for example:

- myserverside.com/users/100
- myserverside.com/users/domain/username

when it comes to your example `boolean isUserNew(int userid)` it is not a REST operation. 
Keep in mind REST only means basic CRUD operations. 
I think you'd just have to get the user's representation and then perform whatever check you need (isNew... isBlonde...)